# Where is the Alfresco PDF Preview saved?

Tags: alfresco

when i click to the info Button next to the Filename in a Workspace there is shown a Preview of the PDF File, but i can't find this Preview in the Database or in the Filesystem, anybody know where it will be generated?

Regards 
Rene

Comment: I would imagine (but do not know for sure, you can wait for a better answer) that it renders without saving. Most of the PDF previews I did in my projects where written directly into (buffered) HTTP stream: faster, no hassle cleaning hard drive, no additional memory consumption etc.

Answer (score 3):

The flash preview of the PDF stored as a rendition of the actual document. It is stored as cm:thumbnail object as a child (rendition child association) of the PDF document and has the thumbnail name (i.e. thumbnails type) "webpreview".

Use the [Alfresco Node Browser](http://localhost:8080/alfresco/faces/jsp/admin/store-browser.jsp), find your PDF document and check it's child associations. You should find the webpreview there. From it's contentUrl you can even find the file in the content store (i.e. on you harddisk).

Comment: Hey and thx for your answer, i navigate throug the nodebrowser to the PDF Document but there NO childobjects? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

A preview should be an instance of a [rendition](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Rendition_Service) in Alfresco. Nodes in Alfresco can have more than 1 rendition (e.g. different quality thumbnails). Renditions of nodes in Alfresco are themselves stored as nodes again, so you should be able to find them using the node browser in the admin panel.

Comment: thx for your answer, but there are no childs under the Document.

Comment: I don't think renditions are generated bij default, but that you have to turn them on, e.g. by adding a space action that uses the Rendition API whenever content is added to a space.

Answer (score 1):

If you navigate to the object using the Node Browser and look at its children, assuming you have already viewed the document in a document library list in Share and have opened the details page to see the preview, you'll see two children listed. One is named "doclib" and the other is named "preview". If you navigate to the doclib child, you will see that it is a PNG. That's the thumbnail shown in the document library list. If you navigate to the "preview" child, you'll see that its mimetype is Flash. That's the flash preview.

If you do not see the flash preview object it is possible that your pdf2swf binary isn't installed correctly or you haven't pointed to it properly in your alfresco-global.properties file.

Comment: Hey Jeff, thx for your answer. When i navigate to a Document with the Nodebrowser, there is no Childelement. But when i click on Previewbutton there is a OCRed preview. I don't know where it saved.

Comment: What is the "Preview" button? That's not part of the standard user interface in either Share or Explorer.

Comment: It is a standard button, we use the Info Button next to the document and in the bottom of this window is a area called Preview. I want to know where this preview is saved. can you help me?